# Issue while changing arrows in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap3-datetimepicker (version ~> 4.17.47) in my sample project and my requirement is to make datepicker. I added the below mentioned code.

```
$('#drop-off-datepicker').datepicker({
      setDate: new Date($('#drop-off-datepicker').attr('value')),
      templates: {
            leftArrow: '&laquo;',
            rightArrow: '&raquo;'
      }
});
```

But the datepicker is getting displayed in [image: this] way. If I change the code in this mode, datepicker will work perfectly.

```
$('#drop-off-datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date($('#drop-off-datepicker').attr('value')));
```

I dont know what I'm doing wrong in the first set of code and I did it with reference to this [link](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#templates). Any help is appreciated.